# Как правильно настроить базовый url в axios?

Tags: axios, vps

Есть VPS сервер, он имеет домен mysite.ru
На нём запущена production сборка.

Проблема такова: внутри она обращается к бэкенду, где адрес запроса указан как

```
127.0.0.1:1337/products
```

Но в консоли я вижу адрес запроса:

```
mysite.ru/127.0.0.1:1337/products
```

production сборка запущена на localhost:3000 с помощью pm2 и nginx.

На локальной машине в режиме разработки все работало.

Код запроса:

```
const server = 'http://127.0.0.1:1337'

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: server,
});
const response = axios.get('/products', {params})
```

Как правильно сконфигурировать и откуда axios берет базовый url?

Comment: `127.0.0.1` в продакшне точно не должно быть. А в остальном, вы забыли указать протокол `http` или `https`.

Comment: Сейчас попробую отпишусь

Comment: Попробовал. Да, действительно. Какая глупая ошибка. Спасибо. Теперь запрос выглядит mysite.ru/products . Было бы здорово, если бы объяснили почему нельзя использовать 127.0.0.1? Это может помочь кому то еще. И не могли бы вы ответить не в комментариях, что бы я выбрал ваш ответ как решение?

Comment: @ДенисБеспалов потому что 127.0.0.1 - это локалхост. Когда клиент откроет ваш сайт, то запросы пойдут к его локальному компьютеру, где, разумеется, нет никакого бэкенда

Comment: Я в целом понимал что это локалхост и имею представления, но думал это работает в пределах установленной машины. т.е. в моем случае будет обращение как бы к локалхосту именно моей машины т.к. он там внутри указан. Понял, спасибо.